# JQuery блокирует набор текста в input

Tags: jquery, html5

При вёрстке страницы столкнулся с такой ситуацией, что невозможно набрать символы в инпуте. В ходе проверки выяснилось, что при отключении jQuery (1.10.2.min) всё работает, символы набираются. Информацию по этому вопросу я к сожалению не нашёл. Как исправить ситуацию и исключить конфликт инпута с jQuery?
Вот пример кода:

```
<div id="access">
  <form id="super" name="super" action="вход.php" method="post">
    <label for="in">Email</label><br>
    <input id="in" name="in" required type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" autofocus><br>
    <label for="wrd">Пароль</label><br>
    <input id="wrd" name="wrd" required type="password" size="20" maxlength="30"><br><br>
    <input id="ent" name="ent" type="submit" value="войти"><br><br>
    <a href="регистрация.php">регистрация</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Без примера кода ответ вы получите только от дипломированного телепата.

Comment: Вы страницу верстаете свою или доверстываете чью-то? Только от одного JQuery такое не происходит, cкорее всего у Вас есть еще какой-то код, который использует JQuery. Посмотрите в консоль браузера на ошибки, может это даст прояснение происходящего.

Comment: Добавил код. Ещё хочу уточнить, что страница основана на HTML5 Boilerplate. Вот ссылка, правда со старым вариантом сайта, но проблема та же: https://googledrive.com/host/0B6xl9-H6tKV_V3ZCd2pKX0kzWUk/. В консоли есть только это: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead

Comment: Всё я разобрался. Дело было таки в скрипте, использующего jQuery. Просто был назначен обработчик нажатия клавиш: $(document).on('keydown', function(e){}) Решил всё назначением аналогичного обработчика на поля формы:
$('#in', '#wrd').on('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) return;
  var echar = getChar(e); 
  if (!echar) return;
}

Comment: Ой, нет! Не нужно так делать! Достаточно просто убрать e.preventDefault() в первом обработчике.